# multithreading or shared memory - Architecture

Tags: multithreading, memory, embedded, shared

There are 3 parts to my application:

1. A numerical simulator solving a 21 variable diff equation by runge-kutta method - direct from numerical recipes in C, step size is 0.0001 s
2. A C code pinging a PIC based micrprocessor every 1s and receiving data at about 3600 samples per second over the USB-COM port; It sends relevant data to the front end over TCP/IP
3. A JAVA front end reading the data from the numerical simulator via SWIG (for the C code) and JNI, modifying the parameters with input from the microprocessor and finally plotting it to the GUI.

I want to recode the JAVA front end  in C++ now, with the option of using HTML/Javascript for plotting.

Would rewriting the front end in C++ so that the numerical simulator runs on a separate thread be a good approach?

I don't understand threading though I have used it for the listening and plotting functions in the JAVA code.  It seems like having it all run on multiple threads instead of separate processes would slow down my simulations.

Can I combine 1 , 2 and 3 into a single program or should they remain separate to retain the 0.0001 ms simulation speed and the ability to handle the large amount to microprocessor data.

Please help me pick a path forward!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you can get the PIC to generate data without being pinged, then you can probably just use the *presumably large* serial receive buffers in the PC operating system to free that from anything approach a realtime constraint.  You would then only need multiple threads if the GUI architecture you are using requires it.

Comment: The pinging is actually a placeholder for a future when I send data back to the processor - infrequent, say once in 3 - 5 s - so I want to design with the pinging in place.

Comment: You are not clear about what platform you are proposing to run this on. The tags suggest it is embedded, but the text suggests otherwise. The embedded tag is largely irrelevant perhaps?

Comment: The tag suggests embedded because I am talking over the USB/COM to pic18 microprocessor.  But, I don't have any issues with any of the code in the microprocessor.  All the issues arise when I try to decide how to scan and use the data from the microprocessor. I am running on a windows XP platform.

Answer (score 0):

On a multicore platform, multithreading will generally improve performance. However, GPOS such as Linux and Windows are not deterministic, so there are no guarantees.

That said, the computational performance of a modern PC is such that it will hardly be stretched by this task and data rate,so it hardly matters perhaps?